# Jquery: Sort by inner element's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, frontend

I have following code:

```
<div>
  <div id="1">
    <h3>Price: 50</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="50"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <h3>Price: 30</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="30"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <h3>Price: 40</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to sort these 3 divs based on *min-price* attribute. Is it possible in Jquery? I found `sort()` function, but I was not able to use it correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
     $("div[id]").each(function(number,ele) {
         
         $("div[id]").not($(ele)).each(function(index,el){
             
             a = $(ele).find("span").attr("min-price");
             b = $(el).find("span").attr("min-price");
             
             if( parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b) )
                 $(ele).insertAfter($(el));
             
         })
         
     })
     
 })
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="1">
    <h3>Price: 50</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="50"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <h3>Price: 30</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="30"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <h3>Price: 40</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sort()` function:

```
$('div[id]').sort(function (a, b) {
  var minprice1 = parseInt( $(a).find('span').attr('min-price'));
  var minprice2 = parseInt( $(b).find('span').attr('min-price'));
  return (minprice1 < minprice2 ) ? -1 : (minprice1 > minprice2 ) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: Since `minprice1` and `minprice2` are `int`s you can use `return minprice1 - minprice2;`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sortElements(element, prop, sortDescending) {
  var arrElements = [], origElements = [];
 
  $.each(element, function(){  
    arrElements.push($(this).attr(prop));
    origElements.push($(this).attr(prop));
  });
  
  arrElements.sort();

  if(sortDescending)
    arrElements.reverse();
  
    
  for(var i = 0, l = arrElements.length; i < l; i++)
    $("#sortDiv").append($("#"+arrElements[i]));
    
  $("#divOrig").html($("#sortDiv").html());
  $("#sortDiv").remove();
}

sortElements($("#divOrig span"), "min-price", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOrig">
  <div id="50">
    <h3>Price: 50</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="50"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="30">
    <h3>Price: 30</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="30"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="40">
    <h3>Price: 40</h3>
    <span id="price" min-price="40"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sortDiv" style="display:none" ></div>
```